# how to call different image urls using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

actually i am working on a project and it gets almost done but i got a problem in my project i have multiple images each image have different url. here it goes suppose if click a image it should call the ajax and if click an another image this image should also call the same ajax ,can any one suggest me how to do that
here is the code what i have used

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#video1').click(function(){
        $data=$(this).attr('data-url');
         $.ajax({
            url : 'playvideo.jsp',
            type : 'POST',
            data : 'url=' + $data,
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(result) {
            },
            error : function(e) {
                alert('Error thrown'+e);                    
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Post some `html` too...

Comment: `$('#video1')` indicates that you only bind the click event to #video. Bind it to all images you want to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

As GolezTrol explained in the comments above, the [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) is too narrow. You could try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // old selector just picked the element with id 'video1'
  // new selector picks all elements of class 'image-clickable'
  $('.image-clickable').click(function(){
    $data=$(this).attr('data-url');
    $.ajax({
      // ..     
    }); 
  });
});
```

And you need some code that adds the `class="image-clickable"` attribute to all image elements, that should get that click handler which fires the AJAX call attached. Or maybe you can add those already to your HTML.